# I am trying to get color id $color_id in below code but here it is returning empty value ?? is anyone have any idea related it

Tags: magento-1.9

```
if(count($productCollection_child['facets']['colour']['buckets']) >= 1)
{
    if(count($productCollection_child['facets']['colour']['buckets']) > 0)
    {
        foreach($productCollection_child['facets']['colour']['buckets'] as &$filetsclr)
        {
            $colorvalue[] = $filetsclr['value'];
            $colorcount[] = $filetsclr['count'];
        }
        $filterHtml .='<div class="odd current_cat_append"><dt>Colour</dt><dd class="odd"><ol>';
        for($i=0;$i<10; $i++)
        {
            $attributeCode = 'color';
            $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
                ->setStoreFilter(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)
                ->addFieldToFilter('tdv.value', $colorvalue[$i]);
            if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
                $color_id = $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
            }
            $clrUrls ='?color='.$color_id;
            $filterHtml .='<li><a href="'.$clrUrls.'" class="current">'.$colorvalue[$i].'<span style="color:#78a818">('.$colorcount[$i].')</span></a></li>';    
        }
        $filterHtml .='</ol></dd><p style="cursor: pointer;font-size: 16px;color: #414141 ! important;" class="showallcolor">show more</p></div>';
    }
}
```

In inspect element it is coming $color_id is empty :

```
<li><a href="?color=" class="current">005 Set (0.2mm Line)<span style="color:#78a818">(1)</span></a></li><li><a href="?color=" class="current">03 Set (0.35mm Line)<span style="color:#78a818">(1)</span></a></li>
```

Comment: `$color_id = $collection->getFirstI tem()->getId();` => remove the space between the 'I' and the 't' in the 'getFirstI tem' ?
Then, try to debug yourself : your $collection->getSize() > 0 ? What the content of $collection->getFirstItem() ? And so on.

Comment: yes its corrected but i am thinking there should not be color values then only it is returning empty

Comment: So $collection->getSize() == 0 ? When you go to you DB and you make a request with store = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID and tdv.value = $colorvalue[$i], did you got any result ?